# Merge Data in while loop and call it outside while loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have 3 data in my inbox table, that is

```
--------------
| id | value |
--------------
| 1 | test1 |
| 2 | test2 |
| 3 | test3 |
--------------
```

i want to merge all data and insert it into one variable 
for example i create `$results` and when i create `echo $results;` outside the while loop 
i want the value and the output is `test1test2test3`

This is my last code

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM inbox");

while($data = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

$results[] = $data['value'];

}
echo "$results";
?>
```

and the result is just `Array`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you are asking:

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM inbox");

while($data = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

    $results .= $data['value'];

}
echo $results;
?>
```

at the end $results will equal test1test2test3

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(inbox.value) as the_values FROM inbox;
```

and on code side:

`echo $data['the_values'];`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
<?php

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM inbox");

    while($data = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
        $results .= $data['value'];
    }

    echo $results;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It prints Array because $results is an array. You might want to write:

echo implode($results);

Also, use mysqli instead of mysql ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM inbox");

while($data = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

$results[] = $data['value'];

}
 $results = implode(" ",$results);
  echo $results;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It prints array because it's array use foreach after to display results

```
<?php
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM inbox");
    $results = array(); //good habbit
    while($data = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    $results[] = $data['value'];
    foreach($results as $result)
        echo $result['id'].'-'.$result['value'].'<br>' ;
?>
```

Also you should consider changing **mysql_*** functions to [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.php) because these functions are depracated and will be removed in future php versions.